# Transfering millions of images -- RSync not good enough

Tags: rsync

We've got a folder, 130GB in size, with millions of tiny (5-20k) image files, and we need to move it from our old server (EC2) to our new server (Hetzner, Germany).

Our SQL files SCP'd over really quickly -- 20-30mb/s atleast -- and the first ~5gb or so of images transfered pretty quick, too.

Then we went home for the day, and coming back in this morning, our images have slowed to only ~5kb/s in transfer. RSync seems to slow down as it hits the middle of the workload. I've looked into alternatives, like [gigasync](http://matthew.mceachen.us/geek/gigasync/) (which doesn't seem to work), but everyone seems to agree rsync is the best option.

We have so many files, doing `ls -al` takes over an hour, and all my attempts at using python to batch up our transfer into smaller parts have eaten all available RAM without successfully completing.

How can I transfer all these files at a reasonable speed, using readily available tools and some light scripting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it will significantly faster, but maybe a

```
cd /folder/with/data; tar cvz | ssh target 'cd /target/folder; tar xvz'
```

will do the trick.

If you can, maybe restructure your file arrangement. In similiar situations, I group the files project-wise or just 1000-wise together so that a single folder doesn't have too many entries at once.

But I can imagine that the necessity of `rsync` (which I otherwise like very well, too) to keep a list of transferred files is responsible for the slowness. If the `rsync` process occupies so much RAM that it has to swap, all is lost.

So another option could be to `rsync` folder by folder.

Comment: shouldn't it be `cd /folder/with/data; tar cvzf - | ssh target 'cd /target/folder; tar xvzf -'`

Comment: @Tilo That would be ok as well; if you omit the `f` option, stdin/stdout is used implicitly.

Comment: @Tilo That's ok, I don't know how portable this is. AFAIK there are compile-time constants which can be changed; originally, `tar` wrote to some kind of tape device by default.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that the performance issue isn't with `rsync` itself, but a result of having that many files in a single directory. Very few file systems perform well with a single huge folder like that. You might consider refactoring that storage to use a hierarchy of subdirectories.

Since it sounds like you're doing essentially a one-time transfer, though, you could try something along the lines of a `tar cf - -C <directory> . | ssh <newhost> tar xf - -C <newdirectory>` - that might eliminate some of the extra per-file communication `rsync` does and the extra round-trip delays, but I don't think that will make a significant improvement...

Also, note that, if `ls -al` is taking an hour, then by the time you get near the end of the transfer, creating each new file is likely to take a significant amount of time (seconds or even minutes), since it first has to check every entry in the directory to see if it's in fact creating a new file or overwriting an old one.